# How to find coordinates from two arrays using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, astropy, astronomy

I have two coordinate arrays of just numbers. They are of different lengths. I am trying to find coordinates that are around the same (off by 1), but I keep getting errors in my for loop. When I try the search around code, it says that it cannot compute because the arrays are of different lengths.

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import match_coordinates_sky
distance1 = np.array(table1['Radius'].astype(float))
distance2 = np.array(table2.astype(float))
c = SkyCoord(ra, dec, distance = distance1*u.kpc)
catalog = SkyCoord(ra=ra1, dec=dec1,distance = distance2*u.kpc)
import numpy as np
idxc, idxcatalog, d2d, d3d = catalog.search_around_sky(c, 1*u.deg)  
np.all(d2d < 1*u.deg)  
idxc, idxcatalog, d2d, d3d = catalog.search_around_3d(c, 1*u.kpc)  
np.all(d3d < 1*u.kpc) 
np.all(c[idxc].separation(catalog[idxcatalog]) == d2d)  
np.all(c[idxc].separation_3d(catalog[idxcatalog]) == d3d) 
scalarc = SkyCoord(1*u.deg, 2*u.deg, distance=distance1*u.kpc)  
d2d = scalarc.separation(catalog)  
catalogmsk = d2d < 1*u.deg  
d3d = scalarc.separation_3d(catalog)  
catalog3dmsk = d3d < 1*u.kpc
```

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5266,) (8407,)

```
for (a,b,c) in zip(ra,dec,distance1):
    for (x,y,z) in zip(ra1, dec1, distance2):
        if np.diff(abs(x),abs(a)) <= 1:
            result = result.append()
            if np.diff(abs(y),abs(b)) <= 1:
                result= result.append()
return(result)
```

slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Could you include any data we need to run the code? `table1` and `table2`, for example. It would also help if you could clean up and document your code.

Comment: The code example would need to be improved as well, for example currently it is impossible to know which lines trigger the exceptions.

Comment: Do you want the closest match or the neighbors in a given radius ? You are `match_coordinates_sky` without using it, tough it seems to me that it would be the one to use (to get the closest match).